# Go: cast any int value to int64 in type switch

Tags: casting, go

I often have a situation, where I expect an `int` (of any type, `int/int8/16/32/64`) and check for it using a type switch

```
switch t := v.(type) {
  case int, int8, int16, int32, int64:
    // cast to int64
  case uint, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64:
    // cast to uint64
}
```

Now I cannot use a direct cast, because `t` in this case will be of type `interface{}`. Do I really have to split this up into `case`s for each integer type?

I know that I could do it via reflection using `reflect.ValueOf(v).Int()`, but shouldn't there be a better (less verbose) way of doing this?

***UPDATE:***

Filed an issue, and Rob advised to just use `reflect` in this case.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why is the original type unknown?

Comment: The better way of doing it is to have your function accept an `int64` and leave casting to the caller.

Comment: @iliacholy not possible if you consider argument lists `func(format string, args...interface{})`, which is the case for this example.

Comment: Rob, not Russ. [Issue 5743: spec: type switch ranges Status: WontFix](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5743#c3)

Comment: Ah sorry, yes Rob. Got rsc@ and r@ mixed up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's hard to give you an opinion without more context but it looks like you're trying to make your implementation too generic, which is common from people that worked mostly with more dynamic languages or w/ generic support.

Part of the process of Learning Go is learning to embrace its type system, and depending on where you're coming from, it can be challenging.

Usually, in Go, you want to support one type that can hold all possible values you need to handle. In your case it would probably be a int64.

Take a look on the math package, for example. It only work with int64 and expect anyone using it to typecast it properly instead of trying to convert everything.

Another option is to use a interface to be type-agnostic, like the sort package does. Basically, any method that are type specific will be implemented outside of your package and you expect certain methods to be defined.

It takes a while to learn and accept these attributes but overall, in the end, it proves to be good in terms of maintainability and robustness. Interfaces ensure you have orthogonality and strong types makes sure you're in control of type conversions, which in the end can cause bugs and also unnecessary copies in memory.

Cheers

Comment: I just figured the language could just provide `intish` etc. types for this case. It's just unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same feeling when I started with Go. In the end, it's a trade-off. It sacrifices a little of magic to give you more orthogonality and control over execution and memory management, which is huge on big applications.

Answer (score 14):

What problem are you trying to solve? The full solution that you've described looks like this:

```
func Num64(n interface{}) interface{} {
    switch n := n.(type) {
    case int:
        return int64(n)
    case int8:
        return int64(n)
    case int16:
        return int64(n)
    case int32:
        return int64(n)
    case int64:
        return int64(n)
    case uint:
        return uint64(n)
    case uintptr:
        return uint64(n)
    case uint8:
        return uint64(n)
    case uint16:
        return uint64(n)
    case uint32:
        return uint64(n)
    case uint64:
        return uint64(n)
    }
    return nil
}

func DoNum64Things(x interface{}) {
    switch Num64(x).(type) {
    case int64:
        // do int things
    case uint64:
        // do uint things
    default:
        // do other things
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve are the redundant switch cases you just listed.

Comment: The switch cases aren't redundant, the types are distinct.

Comment: I know that they're distinct. What I mean with redundant is, that I have to list every distinct type when clearly all of them fit in a `int64/uint64` value.

Comment: Yes, you do have to list all the distinct types, because inside each case statement the type is the distinct type for the case. Insert a `fmt.Printf("%T, %#v\n", n, n)` statement after each case clause in `Num64` to see that that's true. It's a different numeric conversion for each case, different conversion code is generated.

Comment: @peterSO I was also trying to do as OP asked. The idea is that why doesnt the compiler understand that `int64(n)` works with all the types given? the hope is probably to keep the code DRY .

Answer (score 8):

Use the [reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect) package. Notice that this is likely to be a lot slower than unrolling the switch.

```
switch t := v.(type) {
case int, int8, int16, int32, int64:
    a := reflect.ValueOf(t).Int() // a has type int64
case uint, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64:
    a := reflect.ValueOf(t).Uint() // a has type uint64
}
```

Comment: I know that I can use reflection. The question is how to do it without reflection.

Comment: I am afraid the way peterSO described is how you should do it the Go way.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this... convert to a string and then parse the string. Not really efficient but compact. I've put this example in the Go playground here: http://play.golang.org/p/0MCbDfUSHO

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func Num64(n interface{}) int64 {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%d", n)
    i,err := strconv.ParseInt(s,10,64)
    if (err != nil) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return i
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Num64(int8(100)))
    fmt.Println(Num64(int16(10000)))
    fmt.Println(Num64(int32(100000)))
    fmt.Println(Num64(int64(10000000000)))
    fmt.Println(Num64("hello"))
}

// Outputs:
// 100
// 10000
// 100000
// 10000000000
// 0
```

Comment: This is a bad suggestion. Why would someone choose to do this over using `reflect`?

Comment: It is a solution nonetheless

Comment: It only works for int types; it doesn't work for int types and uint types.

Comment: Yeah I agree on second thought its not a good solution. Its a technique (i.e. tostring then parseInt) used sometimes in JavaScript and doesn't translate well at all to Go.